# How to prevent scrolling when scrollbar track clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I still want to allow scrolling by dragging the thumb but I don't want clicking the track to trigger any scrolling. Can this be prevented?

[image]

Comment: page or element?

Comment: @depperm element